# load javascript function on load

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

yet when I slide the slider then only text appears, its not showing anything while loads. I want it should show the corresponding text according to value it get.

```
<div class="progress-bar">
        <p id="amount"></p>
        <div class="progress-section" id="progress-slide"></div>
        <span class="left-0">0%</span>
        <span class="right-100">100%</span>
    </div>

$(function () {
    $("#progress-slide").slider({
        range: "min",
        value:10,
        max: 100,
        animate: true,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").text("$" + ui.value);
            if (ui.value >= 0 && ui.value < 30) {
                $("#amount").text('text testing 1'),
            }
            else if (ui.value > 30 && ui.value < 60) {
                $("#amount").text('text testing 2'),
            } 
            else if (ui.value > 60 && ui.value < 90) {
                $("#amount").text('text testing 3'),
            } 
            else {
                $("#amount").text('text testing 4'),
            }
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val("$" + $("#progress-slide").slider("value"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your function here :
$(document).ready(function(){

});

Then on page load your function will be executed.

Comment: It works @Ranjeet try to remove the Commas and replace them with semi-colon.Because using Commas it'll gives you some errors.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function immediately using `()` at last:

```
$(function () {
    $("#progress-slide").slider({
        range: "min",
        value:10,
        max: 100,
        animate: true,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").text("$" + ui.value);
            if (ui.value >= 0 && ui.value < 30) {
                $("#amount").text('text testing 1'),
            }
            else if (ui.value > 30 && ui.value < 60) {
                $("#amount").text('text testing 2'),
            } 
            else if (ui.value > 60 && ui.value < 90) {
                $("#amount").text('text testing 3'),
            } 
            else {
                $("#amount").text('text testing 4'),
            }
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val("$" + $("#progress-slide").slider("value"));
})();
```